# Next.js with Clerk Auth - how to detect if a user just signed up?

Tags: authentication, next.js, oauth, next.js13, clerk

Using Clerk Auth, I have a working login/sign-up flow with Next.js 13 middleware.

When a user signs up, I want to add a row to my DB's `Users` table.

The problem with middleware is that it runs on every single request and I don't want to make a call to my database to check if the user exists so I can create a record.

Does Clerk return any data that I can use to differentiate a sign-up vs a normal request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might need to create webhooks that listen to `user.created`. See

- https://clerk.com/docs/users/sync-data-to-your-backend
- https://reference.clerk.dev/v/master/backend/webhooks

Comment: Nice Erikz! I also wrote this one which relates https://clerk.com/blog/exploring-clerk-metadata-stripe-webhooks

Answer (score 3):

So I ended up going another route because I didn't want to create webhooks for my specific case (although I believe in most cases, that's what you'd want to do).

For me, I ended up using Clerk's metadata system. Basically you can attach metadata to a user on their system, see [here](https://clerk.com/docs/users/metadata).

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { clerkClient } from "@clerk/nextjs";
 
export async function POST() {
  const { stripeId, userId } = await body.json();
  await clerkClient.users.updateUserMetadata(userId, {
    privateMetadata: {
      stripeId: stripeId
    }
  });
  return NextResponse.json({ success: true });
}
```

In my case, I attach my own system's user UUID to Clerk's user. Then, in my middleware, I check if this exists (it's in the session data, so it won't make a request to Clerk's servers), if it doesn't exist, I know it's a new year and I run the signup flow, otherwise carry on with normal operations.

I'll set the other answer as the correct answer, but I'll leave this answer here for anyone with a similar use case trying to avoid webhooks.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article that handles this specific kind of situation. I see that you went with a more personal route for your needs but wanted to still callout this

Article: https://clerk.com/blog/exploring-clerk-metadata-stripe-webhooks

Example Repo: https://github.com/JacobMGEvans/stripe-with-webhooks-and-metadata

The code similar to your updating the private metadata, I utilize the public metadata for future uses in the frontend of that data in the users session.

```
case "checkout.session.completed":
  const session = event.data.object;
  console.log(`Payment successful for session ID: ${session.id}`);
        // That's it? Yep, that's it. We love UX 
        clerkClient.users.updateUserMetadata(
    event.data.object.metadata?.userId as string,
    {
      publicMetadata: {
        stripe: {
          status: session.status,
          // This is where we get "paid"
          payment: session.payment_status,
        },
      },
    }
  );
```